# move directory and files if directory contains a specific string(remove string from directory name)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

edited to better explain question.

so I want to scan a directory, look for subdirectories containing --import-me at the end of the directory name, move to a new directory with all files contained, just rename the dir without the --import-me string

```
cd $some-dir
for f in `find . -name "*--import-me" `
do
rename=${f%--import-me}
echo mv $f "some-other-dir"/"$rename"
done
```

I get

```
mv ./iZombie /some-other-dir/./iZombie
mv (2015)--import-me /some-other-dir/(2015)
```

I expect it to give me

```
mv ./some-other-dir/iZombie (2015)
```

Comment: You don't need `echo | sed`, just `${file%--import-me}` is enough. You also have typos. Other than that, you didn't really say what's your problem. You only made a statement.

Comment: Define "does not work". That's the most important part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your example that the `*--import-me` directories exist only in the current directory, if so you can use this one-liner:

```
find . -type d -name "*--import-me" -exec sh -c 'mv $0 some-dir/${0%--import-me}' {} \;
```

Otherwise if you have nesting directories you must use this one, note that if there are `/` in the target directory (`some-dir`) you will have to escape them `\/`:

```
find . -type d -name "*--import-me" -exec sh -c 'mv $0 `echo $0| sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)--import-me/some-dir\/\1/g"`' {} \;
```

Comment: something like this could work... but still doesn't 


`mv "$dldDir"/*_import-me "$libDir"`
`mv "$libDir"/*_import-me "$libDir"/${0%_import-me}`

Answer (score 0):

so I can't seem to get this to work, the filename always gets split at spaces, so it tries to mv two separate dirs.
this is running from a script, ideally would be to find directories containing "*_import-me", rename and move in one command, but now I am trying to move dirs (from $dldDir to $libDir) containing _import-me, then rename dirs in libDir (removing the string _import-me)

```
mv "$dldDir"/*_import-me "$libDir"
cd $libDir
find . -type d -name "*_import-me" -exec sh -c 'mv $0 `echo $0| sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)_import-me/"$libDir"\/\1/g"`' {} \;
```

So, the first mv works, and a ls $dldDir gives me

```
~# ls -1 $dldDir
Brother Bear 2 (2006)_import-me
Terminator Salvation (2009)_import-me
```

but the second mv(removing _import-me in $libDir) I get

```
mv: target ‘(2009)_import-me’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘(2006)_import-me’ is not a directory
```